# iPhone, if possible to get a photo from album without use UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone

as topic, I want iPhone app can access the photo album and got a photo but without popup the UIImagePickerController, does it possible ?

thanks for tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, with iOS 4 or later.  Look at the documentation for `ALAssetsLibrary` and the associated `AssetsLibrary.framework`.  You would have to determine what media you're interested in yourself and basically handle all the niceness the built-in picker does for you.